# Describing A Congruence Class

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, equivalence-relations

The question is, "Give a description of each of the congruence classes modulo 6."

Well, I began saying that we have a relation, $R$, on the set $Z$, or, $R \subset Z \times Z$, where $x,y \in Z$. The relation would then be $R=\{(x,y)|x \equiv y~(mod~6)\}$

Then, $[n]_6 =\{x \in Z|~x \equiv n~(mod~6)\}$

$[n]_6=\{x \in Z|~6|(x-n)\}$

$[n]_6=\{x \in Z|~k(x-n)=6\}$, where $n \in Z$

As I looked over what I did, I started think that this would not describe all of the congruence classes on modulo 6.  Also, what would I say k is? After despairing, I looked at the answer key, and they talked about there only being 6 equivalence classes. Why are there only six of them? It also says that you can describe equivalence classes as one set, how would I do that?

Comment: Given an element in $Z$, its equivalence class is the set of all elements in $Z$ that are related to that particular element. So pick an integer. Can you describe all the integers that are related to that integer?

Comment: @EMACK: Have the varied answers helped to clarify why there are exactly six equivalence classes?

Comment: @amWhy Yes, most certainly. Thank you for asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let’s start with your correct description

$$[n]_6=\{x\in\Bbb Z:x\equiv n\!\!\!\pmod 6\}=\{x\in\Bbb Z:6\mid x-n\}$$

and actually calculate $[n]_6$ for some values of $n$.

- $[0]_6=\{x\in\Bbb Z:6\mid x-0\}=\{x\in\Bbb Z:6\mid x\}=\{x\in\Bbb Z:x=6k\text{ for some }k\in\Bbb Z\}$; this is just the set of all multiples of $6$, so $[0]_6=\{\dots,-12,-6,0,6,12,\dots\}$.
- $[1]_6=\{x\in\Bbb Z:6\mid x-1\}=\{x\in\Bbb Z:x-1=6k\text{ for some }k\in\Bbb Z\}$; this isn’t quite so nice, but we can rewrite it as $\{x\in\Bbb Z:x=6k+1\text{ for some }k\in\Bbb Z\}$, the set of integers that are one more than a multiple of $6$; these can be described as the integers that leave a remainder of $1$ when divided by $6$, and $[1]_6=\{\dots,-11,-5,1,7,13,\dots\}$.

More generally, if $x$ is any integer, we can write it as $x=6k+r$ for integers $k$ and $r$ such that $0\le r<6$: $r$ is the remainder when $x$ is divided by $6$. Then

$$\begin{align*}
[r]_6&=\{x\in\Bbb Z:6\mid x-r\}\\
&=\{x\in\Bbb Z:x-r=6k\text{ for some }k\in\Bbb Z\}\\
&=\{x\in\Bbb Z:x=6k+r\text{ for some }k\in\Bbb Z\}\\
&=\{6k+r:k\in\Bbb Z\}\;
\end{align*}$$

the set of all integers leaving a remainder of $r$ when divided by $6$. You know that the only possible remainders are $0,1,2,3,4,5$, so you know that this relation splits $\Bbb Z$ into exactly six equivalence classes, $[0]_6,[1]_6,[2]_6,[3]_6,[4]_6$, and $[5]_6$.

Answer (score 4):

Take any $n \in \mathbb{Z}.$

Then for each such $n$ there is an integer $k$ such that one of the following equations are satisfied. $$n=6k + 0$$ $$n=6k+1$$ $$n=6k+2$$ $$n=6k+3$$ $$n=6k+4$$

$$n=6k+5$$

Can any integer satisfy *more* than one of the above equalities?

Can any integer *NOT* satisfy any of of the above equalities?

Then we can describe the equivalence classes of the equivalence relation $\equiv_{6}$ (congruence, mod $6$) as they relate to the *division algorithm*:

> Given any $d \in \mathbb{Z}, d>0$, we know that $\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}$, there exist unique integers $q, r$ such that  $n = dq + r$ where $0\leq r< d$.

In this problem, we have the divisor $d = 6$ of a given $n$:

- $k = q\in \mathbb{Z}$ is the unique corresponding *quotient* which results when dividing $n$ by $d = 6$, and
- $r$ is the unique *corresponding remainder*, $0\le r < d = 6$, left after dividing that $n$ by $6$.

---

Then the corresponding equivalence classes can be defined in terms of the the remainder $r$:
 $$[r]_6 \in \{[0]_6,[1]_6, [2]_6, [3]_6, [4]_6, [5]_6\} \;\text{ where}$$

$$ [0]_6 = \{...,-12,-6,0,6,12,...\}$$
$$[1]_6 = \{...-11,-5,1,7,13,...\}$$
$$[2]_6 = \{...-10,-4,2, 8, 14...\}$$
$$ \vdots$$
$$[5]_6 = \{...-7,-1,5, 11, 17,...\}$$

Comment: Anothe long Tale is here +

Answer (score 1):

You're right, it does not describe all the congruence classes -- due to an error. Namely, notice $\rm\:6\mid x\!-\!n\:$ means $\rm\:6\color{#C00}k = x\!-\!n,\:$ not $\rm\:6 = \color{#C00}k(x\!-\!n).\:$ Recall $\rm\:a\mid b \!\iff\! a\color{#C00}k = b\:$ for some $\rm\:\color{#C00}k\in\Bbb Z.$ Thus $\rm\:x\in [n]_6$ $\!\iff\!$ $\rm\exists k\in \Bbb Z\!:\ x = n + 6k$ $\!\iff\!$ $\rm x\in n + 6\,\Bbb Z = \{\ldots n\!-\!12,\ n\!-\!6,\ n,\ n\!+\!6,\ n\!+\!12,\ldots\}.$

Comment: And would this describe all of the congruence classes?

Comment: @EMACK Yes, since above $\rm\:n\:$ denotes an arbitrary integer.

Comment: Very nice--it's quite succinct.